# Do I need to use thread synchronisation tools in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am using the Python 2.7 runtime on Google App Engine 1.7.4 with `threadsafe: true` in my app.yaml.

I have the following code:

```
@ndb.tasklet
def fn_a(container):
    ''' access datastore and mutate container '''

@ndb.tasklet
def fn_b(container):
    ''' access datastore and mutate container '''

@ndb.toplevel
def parallel_fn():
    shared_container = set()

    yield fn_a(shared_container), fn_b(shared_container)
```

`fn_a()` and `fn_b()` both access and mutate `shared_container` and are called in `parallel_fn()`. `shared_container` is a standard library `set` and therefore is not thread safe.

Should I wrap the mutator/accessor methods of `shared_container` in the appropriate `threading` standard library locks?

From what I understand of App Engine each instance is single threaded despite setting `threadsafe: true`. Therefore is the use of the `threading` lock objects not required?

Preliminary tests show locks are not required and would just add extra overhead as well as deadlock. It also seems the following should not be done

```
if object not in shared_container:
    yield any tasklet operation
    shared_container.add(object)
```

as `shared_container` might be updated by another line of execution during the `yield` operation rendering the `object not in shared_container` statement potentially invalid. However

```
if object not in shared_container:
    shared_container.add(object)
    yield any tasklet operation
```

would be absolutely fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add locking code because tasklets don't run in separate threads.  Read up about it in the [tasklet docs.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#tasklets)

GAE is multithreaded if you set threadsafe: true.  Different threads are launched to handle multiple requests on the same instance.  Generally this is not a problem, since you're supposed to design your request handlers to be able to run across various server instances anyways.

This doesn't really apply to this question, but if you ever really do test threading issues, be careful.  I'm not certain but I believe threading behavior is different between running on dev_appserver and production GAE servers, so make sure you test on both.